# Defining docstring raises for functions not explicitly raising exception

Tags: python, exception, docstring

```
import requests

def example():
    """An example function

    :raises KeyError: ?
    :raises HttpError: ?
    """
    result: Dict = do_something()
    log(result["key"])
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response
```

The above function is not explicitly raising any exception, but as can be seen, its execution can potentially raise `KeyError` and `HTTPError`. Is it fine to mention these in docstring? What does the best practice say?

Comment: All the more valuable to mention it in the docstring if it's not obvious by skimming the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, but it is not a full answer either, because it is based on what I have noticed and because there are no strict rules, e.g. the item 3 below is an exception from item 2.

1. Don't care about exceptions resulting from incorrect usage or problems with a computer that prevent normal program operation like disk full.
2. If some exceptions can happen when the functions is used correctly (it should be documented what that means), they are part of the interface and should be documented.
3. Networking is full of timeouts, outages, refused connections etc. Such error is always a possible outcome when network I/O is involved. This is probably considered a well known fact and it is usually not mentioned in docstrings.
   For example the requests.get` appearing in the OP's code does not mention exceptions it may raise (link:
   https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.get
   ). It says you'll get a response. But what you get if there is no valid response? An exception, of course.

Comment: I am not sure how to read "failed connections so that they may be consider normal". Do you mean, these errors occur even when used correctly and therefore need to be documented, or that they are so normal, they don't need to be documented?

Comment: @Neuron Sorry, I'm not a native speaker. What I mean is that it is  "normal" to expect that an error might happen when networking is involved. There is no need to mention this obvious fact in the docs for every function.

Comment: no worries, me neither :) well, then I would like to counter your argument. As someone using an IO function I might expect "an exception" to be raised, I give you that. But I would like to know __which__ exception could be raised, so I can precisely catch that exception. Just generally catching anything that inherits from `Exception` should be avoided, but I have no other choice if the function doesn't tell me what to expect

Comment: On another note, your link is broken. The whole website https://docs.python-requests.org seems to be offline

Comment: I do accept that your opinion is different and I find your argument valid.. My opinion is that stating obvious things is kind of "noise" possibly hiding the important "signal". All (or almost all?) networking errors fall under the `OSError`. That is documented in the `socket` module, but not repeated again and again at individual functions in the `socket` docs. Even the authors of the documentation did not think it is necessary.

Comment: @Neuron I have updated the broken link and edited my answer hoping to be better understandable now. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Interesting, I did not even know the `OSErrors` was standard for all things networking ans IO. I am quite an experienced python developer, but maybe I just don't do enough network stuff. Knowing that, it does make much more sense to leave it out. And on Monday I will change some code to inherit from `OSError` for sure ;)

Answer (score 4):

If the exceptions are relavant for somebody using the functions the should be documented (and also that they are indirect)